# Conjecture on continuous selection of fixed points of a correspondence

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I have the following conjecture to show some sort of a continuous
selection of fixed points in a correspondence:

Let $S$ and $\Theta $ be non-empty, compact and convex subsets of some
Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $\Gamma :$ $S\times \Theta \rightarrow
2^{S}$ be a set-valued function on $S\times \Theta $ with a closed graph and
the property that $\Gamma \left( x,\theta \right) $ is non-empty and convex
for all $x$ $\in $ $S$ and all $\theta \in \Theta $. Moreover, for all $x\in
S$, $\Gamma \left( x,\cdot \right) $ is lower hemicontinuous with respect to 
$\Theta $. Then, for all $\theta \in \Theta $, there exist a non empty,
upper-hemicontinuous, convex-valued correspondence $x^{\ast }:\Theta
\rightarrow S$ such that $x\in \Gamma \left( x,\tilde{\theta}\right) $ for
all $x\in x^{\ast }\left( \tilde{\theta}\right) $ and all $\tilde{\theta}$
in a neighborhood of $\theta $.

The proof of the non-empty and upper-hemicontinuity part is easy. For all $%
\tilde{\theta}$ in a neighborhood of $\theta $ apply the Kakutani Fixed
Point Theorem and set $x^{\ast }\left( \tilde{\theta}\right) $ equal to the
fixed point. Then, consider a sequence $\left \{ x^{k},\theta ^{k}\right \}
\rightarrow \left( x,\theta \right) $ such that $x^{k}\in x^{\ast }\left(
\theta ^{k}\right) $. It follows that $x^{k}\in \Gamma \left( x^{k},\theta
^{k}\right) $ for all $k$. Because $\Gamma $ has a closed graph, $x\in
\Gamma \left( x,\theta \right) $.

The challenge is to use lower hemicontinuity of $\Gamma $ with respect to $%
\theta $ to show the existence of a convex-valued correspondence. Are you
aware of any result that proves this conjecture? Can you think of a
counterexample?